# Request args not formatting the way I'd like in app route

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, args

I'm trying to generate a filter for SQL alchemy DB. I'm able to run the query correctly and get the desired result however I need to get the requests correctly and format it accordingly.

I'm hitting the url like:

```py
http://localhost:3000/books?filter=price,eq,37&filter=code,eq,50
```

When I get the args they come out as:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('filter', 'price,eq,37'), ('filter', 'code,eq,50')])
```

But what I really want is:

```
{"filter": ["price,eq,37", "code,eq,50"]}
```

Getting the request like:

```py
@app.route('/books', methods=['GET'])
def books() -> str:
  args = request.args
  print(args)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `flat=False` parameter to the `request.args.to_dict()` method for getting multiple query values for a single key.

Example:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    query_params = request.args.to_dict(flat=False)
    # print(query_params)
    return query_params
```

Kindly do upvote the solution, If you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Method [`lists()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.lists) returns an iterable of `(key, values)`:

```
dict(request.args.lists()) # returns {"filter": ["price,eq,37", "code,eq,50"]}
```

Method [`getlist()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) returns all values of a key:

```
request.args.getlist('filter') # returns ["price,eq,37", "code,eq,50"]
```

Comment: This returns - ImmutableMultiDict([('filter', 'defense,eq,37'), ('filter', 'attack,eq,50')]). I'd like {"filter": ["price,eq,37", "code,eq,50"]}